# How can I make part of an image transparent in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, photo-editing

I would like to know how can I make part of an image transparent in Lightroom. I know how to do that in Photoshop, and I could go to the `Photo` menu in Lightroom and click `Edit in Adobe Photoshop CC 2019` in the `Edit in` submenu, but that's a bit complicated, so I want to know how to do this in Lightroom. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible in Lightroom. You can apply selective edits (such as contrast, exposure etc.) with the adjustment brush or gradient tools, but working with layers, compositing or pixel level adjustment require software such as Photoshop or Gimp.